# Scroll animating with setInterval() instead of setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I want to animate smooth body scrolling on my website with the following script:

```
function autoScroll(el) {
    var scrollY = 0;
    var distance = 2;
    var speed = 10;

    var scrolling = function(){
        var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
        var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
        var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
        var yPos = currentY + window.innerHeight;
        var animator = setInterval('autoScroll(\''+el+'\')', speed)
        interval = animator;

        if (yPos > bodyHeight){
            clearInterval(animator);
        }else{
            if (currentY < targetY - distance){
                scrollY = currentY + distance;
                window.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
            }else if (currentY > targetY + distance){
                scrollY = currentY - distance;
                window.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
            }else{
                clearInterval(animator);
            }
        }
    }
    return scrolling();
}
```

The script runs, but misbehaves. When I click on the menu for the first time it scrolls nicely to the right position and then the scrolling stops. But when I click on the menu for the second time the script never stops scrolling, and it tries to scroll in both directions at the same time, in a random-like fashion. Curiously, when I use setTimeout() and clearTimeout() functions instead of setInterval() and cleatIntervaw the function works just fine. The reason it has to be setInterval() is because the animation is so much snappier than when I use setTimeout().
Can someone explain to me why this anomaly happens and how to fix it?
Appreciated
Jared
UPDATE
Here's the html markup I'm using to scroll:

```
<a href="#" class="scroll" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScroll('location');"><div class="tableLink">Location</div></a>
...
<div id="location" class="page">location</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I don't have time to write a comprehensive answer, but the problem is you're setting up multiple (simultaneous) intervals because you call `setInterval()` from within the function that is called by `setInterval()`. Also, regarding your assertion that it "has to be" `setInterval()` rather than `setTimeout()` to make the animation "snappier": no, no it doesn't. You've said your `setInterval()` version doesn't actually work, so how can it be better than `setTimeout()`? You should be able to use either as long as you get the implementation details correct.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle. I have no idea on what your 'el' is.

Comment: If you are going to animate such an expensive thing as scroll please use requestAnimationFrame instead of JS timers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clear out the interval when you call the function?

```
function autoScroll(el) {
    if (window.interval) window.clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you have made a more complicated solution than necessary. The fact that each interval creates a new function which is then returned looks a bit strange.

You could break up the problem into two:

1. First setup a target element.
2. Then start a loop once with setInterval (only if it's not running already) that scrolls the page towards the target until the target is reached (the code can be written to work even if the target changes in the middle of a loop).

Also, to get the smoothest experience you should consider using requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval.

Finally, if you don't mind using jQuery, there's lots of plugins that already offer this functionality, such as http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/. It might be worth checking that out.

Comment: Thanks Strille. I am using the newest version of Zurb's Foundation 4. I tried several scrolling jQuery solutions, but for some reason none of them works. No clue why. That is why I found this, pure JavaScript, solution which somewhat works. Please see my question again. I'm about to make an update with a sample of my html markup.